# Externally linked stylesheet is not changing anything

Tags: html, css

Here is the head of my document:

```
<title>My Form</title>
<script src="navigation.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="navigation.css" type="text/css">
<!--style>
    .form-section {
        display: none;
    }

    .form-section.current {
        display: block;
    }
</style-->
```

When I uncomment the style block, things work fine. When commented though, nothing works, in spite of navigation.css having exactly the same code. Also, I can see that navigation.css is correctly being fetched in the network tab.

What might be preventing it from styling the page when loading styles externally?

Edit: This is what's in navigator.css:

```
.form-section {
    display: none;
}

.form-section .current {
    display: block;
}

.demo-form {
    border: solid;
}

form {
    border: solid;
}
```

For what it's worth, that's what I'm seeing get returned in the network tab too:
[image: network tab]

But it's blank in the sources tab:
[image: sources tab]

Headers:
[image: Headers]

Comment: Also it should be noted that navigation.js works just fine

Comment: try without type like this. <link rel="stylesheet" href="navigation.css"> might be type="text/css" may be this issue. just try

Comment: Whats in the stylesheet?

Comment: What does https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ have to say about it?

Comment: @putvande I added that above. Basically the same as what's in the commented-out style block.

Comment: @Quentin Just tried it, it validated without any errors

Comment: @AniruddhaDas thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that was not the issue.

Comment: `navigation.css` is in the same directory as your HTML document? (filepath...)

Comment: @Johannes Yep. It gets the file correctly, which you can see in the network tab. However, in the sources tab, it's blank (see the pictures I attached)

Comment: Can you please post screenshot of the headers? It might be that your server isn't serving CSS file with correct mime-type

Comment: @canisminor Added it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with nginx serving up the file correctly. Had to add this line to the location block in nginx.conf:

```
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

Comment: Please tag this as a response - it will be helpful for future users that might encounter this issue

Comment: @canisminor I have to wait two days after adding the answer to do that